# ToolStripMenuItem needs to restrict only right click

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to restrict only right click for my ToolStripMenuItem but there is not any particular event that can return Keys.

I used **MouseDown**, **MouseUp** events also, but there enter key not working so I need to use only **Click** events but click event can't help me to identify keys.

Comment: Could you clarify what does enter key have to do with right-click?

Comment: I need to support only left click and enter key for menu items, that's why I mention it.

Comment: `only left click and enter` So, you want to stop the item from activating when it's clicked by the right mouse button. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @defaultlocale Yes, it's my actual requirement but I can't achieve it by ToolStripMenuItem, that's why I asked here.

Answer (score 1):

In your event handling method you can check what Mousebutton has been pressed.

In the event MouseUp you have access to the mousebutton property of the MouseEventArgs.

```
if(e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
{
   doStuff();
}
```

Comment: ToolStripMenuItem click event gets `EventArgs` and not `MouseEventArgs`, therefore it does not have `e.Button`

Comment: @styx The answer is probably referring to the MenuStrip/ContextMenuStrip parent, which provides a `MouseClick` event that can be used to determine what mouse button was clicked in the currently selected ToolStripMenuItem. @Henry Specify in the answer what object provides the event you mentioned.

Comment: @Jimi Oh, thank you! Yes, I was referring to the ToolStrip itself. The ToolStripMenuItem has an event MouseUp in which you can access the Button-Property as well. Thank you for clarifying/correcting. :-)

Comment: @Henry I try that but in that case, my Enter key not working, so this solution does not work for me.

Comment: @HirenJasani Ah, now I get it. That could be a little bit tricky.

I think one of the upper containers like the ToolStrip itself should fire a KeyPressed Event or something like that.

There you can evaluate the pressed Key and might also get the ToolStripMenuItem-Instance as the sender.

But I'm not shure about that. Maybe it'll work for you. Best of luck!